# Dynamic Expression for Ordering Child Collections with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sorting, dynamic, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-4.1

I am new to EF. I am trying to get Entity Framework 4.2 to do a sort by a calculated property (not mapped).

Here is what my entity look like:

```
    public class Site : Entity
    {
        public Site()
        {
            Equipments = new HashSet<Equipment>();
            Forecasts = new HashSet<Forecast>();
        }

        [StringLength(8)]
        public string Number { get; set; }

        [StringLength(50)]
        public string EquipmentShortCLLI { get; set; }

        [StringLength(50)]
        public string Location { get; set; }

        public virtual Central Central { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Equipment> Equipments { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Forecast> Forecasts { get; set; }


        #region Calculated Items

        public bool IsEmbargo {
            get { return Equipments.Count > 0 && Equipments.SelectMany(x => x.EquipmentDetails).Any(e => e.IsEmbargo); }
        }


//...

        public int PortsCapacity
        {
            get
            {
                return Equipments.Count > 0
                           ? Equipments.SelectMany(x => x.Slots).Sum(x => x.PortsCapacity)
                           : 0;
            }
        }
        #endregion
//...
```

By trying to order using any of my readonly properties I am getting the exception:
The specified type member 'PortsCapacity' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported.

Which makes sense because EF is trying to build an sql orderby with a field that does not exist in the database (my understanding..).

Now, by using [some dynamic linq code](http://landman-code.blogspot.com/2008/11/linq-to-entities-string-based-dynamic.html) I was able to make this work for my many-to-one columns by passing "Central.SomeField" (as opposed to making a ReadOnly Property that returns Central.SomeField). 
I.E.:

```
query.OrderBy("Central.SomeField");
```

However, I still face the same issue when it comes to a collection of items (Equipments). I am trying to make this as dynamic as possible by using a string coming from the client side and avoiding a long switch case, but at this point I will accept any ideas, so long as **the sorting happens on the database side**.

**Edit 1:**

Following what Ladislav Mrnka says, how would one execute an OrderBy clause on one-to-many child items using lambdas or expression?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that Dynamic Linq is capable of this. You need a real Linq subquery to compute aggregations on `Equipements` so it will simply not work. If the user selects ordering by `IsEmbargo` or `PortsCapacity` you must have some `switch` / `if` block to handle this case by appending special part of the query - no other way.

Comment: What If I know what to sort on and use a switch to sort by ports capacity or IsEmbargo? Basically, How would I write my case knowing what I need to sort on with a child collection using Linq to entities?